# Basic render test for react loadable components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-loadable

I have a component that I'm dynamically loading

```
const Summary = loadable({ 
   loader: () => import( /* webpackChunkName: "summary" */ 'app/components/summary')
   resolveModule: module => module.default,
});
```

Problem: My module wasn't resolving correctly and hence the component didn't render on the screen.

Test: Component should render

While testing with jest, I'm getting either a timeout ( when using done ) or my component isn't loading in the first tick which causes the test case to fail.